# Given equations for the side-lines of a parallelogram, why are these the equations for the diagonal-lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, proof-explanation

My book, for a parallelogram $ABCD$ with sides as 
$$\begin{align}
AB&\;\equiv\; a\phantom{^\prime}x+b\phantom{^\prime}y  +c\phantom{^\prime}=0 \\
BC&\;\equiv\; a^\prime x         +b^\prime y           +c^\prime=0 \\ 
CD&\;\equiv\; a\phantom{^\prime}x+b\phantom{^\prime} y +c^\prime=0 \\
DA&\;\equiv\; a^\prime x         +b^\prime y           +c\phantom{^\prime}=0
\end{align}$$
wrote equation of diagonals: 
$$AC\;\equiv\; (ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c)-(a'x+b'y+c')(ax+by+c')=0$$
$$BD\;\equiv\; (ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c')-(a'x+b'y+c)(ax+by+c')=0$$

I don't understand why. Please help.

Comment: I had actually set the bounty for this question, I'd like to more clearly state why exactly I did so, would someone please give an answer with a little more explanation, especially stressing on the point of why the equations of diagonals (taking AC for instance) is for the entire line AC and not just points A and C?

Comment: @Hema: If a first-degree equation, say, $p x + q y = r$, is satisfied by two points, then it's satisfied by *all* points on the line joining those two points. If you want help understanding that fact, then it would probably be better to ask a separate question instead of muddying the purpose of this particular question. (There may be other questions on Math.SE that address this issue. For instance, ["Linear equations: standard line equation proof"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2845815/409).)

Comment: @Blue: It seems that Hema has already known that. I think that he/she is asking if the equation is actually the **line** $AC$. See my answer.

Comment: @mathlove: I don't see how your answer explains the line connection any better than, say, Michael's does. You both claim that the equations represent lines; the only difference is that you put the word in **boldface**. (Of course, that's not completely true. You go through the trouble of showing that the equations simplify to $px+qy=r$ form.)  Hema needs to clarify what exactly the source of confusion is.

Comment: @Blue: For example, $px+qy=r$ does not represent a line when $p=q=r=0$. My understanding is that he/she is asking if the equation does represent a line. OK, let us wait his/her clarification:)

Comment: @Blue actually I had wanted a clarification on the point that mathlove addressed. I had actually been aware of the fact that if two points satisfy a line equation the whole line satisfies it, but I found I needed to solidify that concept a bit more. The link you gave did help me to further clarify that point rather than have the slightly foggy understanding I had previously, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It should be:
$$BD\equiv (ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c)-(a'x+b'y+c')(ax+by+c')=0$$$$AC\equiv (ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c')-(a'x+b'y+c)(ax+by+c')=0$$

Because

1. they are equations of straight lines,
2. $(x_1,y_1)$ is placed on the line $ax+by+c=0$ iff $ax_1+by_1+c=0$ and
3. there is an unique straight line which goes through two distinct points.

Done!

Comment: please read John Betin's answer, there is contradiction between two.

Comment: @mathlover I saw it and I added something in my post. I think you made a typo,  See please better.

Answer (score 1):

These equations are wrong. For example, at the point $A$, the two factors of the first term in the expression for $AC$ are zero, while the remaining term, and so the whole expression, evaluates to $-(c'-c)^2$, which generally is not zero—and similarly for $B$ on $BD$.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Rozenberg has written, they should be
$$\small BD\equiv (ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c)-(a'x+b'y+c')(ax+by+c')=0\tag1$$$$\small AC\equiv (ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c')-(a'x+b'y+c)(ax+by+c')=0\tag2$$

> why the equations of diagonals (taking AC for instance) is for the entire line AC and not just points A and C?

$(1)$ can be written as
$$aa'x^2+ab'xy+acx+a'bxy+bb'y^2+bcy+ca'x+cb'y+c^2-aa'x^2-a'bxy-a'c'x-ab'xy-bb'y^2-b'c'y-ac'x-bc'y-c'^2=0,$$
i.e.
$$(a+a')(c-c')x+(b+b')(c-c')y+(c-c')(c+c')=0\tag3$$

Suppose that $c=c'$. Then, the equations of $AB$ and $CD$ are the same, which is impossible. So, we have $c\not=c'$.

So, dividing the both sides of $(3)$ by $c-c'$ gives
$$(a+a')x+(b+b')y+c+c'=0\tag4$$

Suppose that $a+a'=0$ and $b+b'=0$. Then, the equation of $DA$ is $ax+by-c=0$. So, the line $DA$ is parallel to the line $AB$, which is impossible. So, we have $a+a'\not=0$ or $b+b'\not=0$.

It follows that $(4)$, i.e. $(1)$ is the equation of the **line** $BD$ (assuming that you've already known that $B,D$ satisfy the equation).

Also, $(2)$ can be written as$$(a-a')x+(b-b')y=0\tag5$$

Suppose that $a-a'=0$ and $b-b'=0$. Then, the equations of $AB$ and $DA$ are the same, which is impossible. So, we have $a-a'\not=0$ or $b-b'\not=0$.

It follows that $(5)$, i.e. $(2)$ is the equation of the **line**  $AC$.

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for! I actually can only award the bounty in 9 hours, so I'll be doing so as soon as I can.