# Linear equations: standard line equation proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Now, in the module on linear equations on Khan Academy deal with a variety of equations of straight lines and faced a problem. I can't find anywhere why the standard equation of a straight line is actually true.

Why any line is determined by the equation Ax + By = C, and this equation in turn always sets a line in the plane. Can somebody recommend a resource/tutorial where this is explained or explain it in a nutshell ?

Comment: If two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and  $(x_2, y_2)$ are on a line the slope between them is $m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$. A straight line, by definition, has the same slope everywhere so that if $( x,y)$ is on the line then the same slope is $m = \frac{y - y_1}{x - x_1}$. Equate the two slopes, do a bit of algebra and you end up with one form of a line, $Ax+By = C$.

Comment: Oh, it's easier than I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that $Ax+By=C$ is the general equation for a straight line, we need a definition of "straight line." You might be tempted to define a straight line as "a curve such that it is the path of shortest distance between any two points on itself," but showing that $Ax+By=C$ gives the shortest distance between any two points is a somewhat long story, so I hope you'll be satisfied with defining a straight line as "a path of constant slope," i.e., for any two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, the slope $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ is constant (depends on the line but not on the particular points). Now, every line has at least one point and a slope, and if we fix a point $(x_0,y_0)$ and a slope $m$, we must have the equation $$ m = \frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}$$ which rearranges to $Ax+By=C$ form. The one exceptional case is the "infinite slope" vertical line $y=C$ which is already in the desired form. Conversely, if we have $Ax+By=C$, we can show slope is constant: taking two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, we get $A(x_2-x_1) + B(y_2-y_1)=0$, which rearranges to an equation of constant slope.